# How do i get the position of a child element

Tags: jquery, html

i need to find the position of a child element.

i have a table and when a td is clicked, i want the position of the td(0,1 or 2)

```
<table>
<tr>
 <td>   

 </td>
 <td>   

 </td>
 <td>

 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and a script like this

```
<script>
$("td").click(function(){
  //how do i get the position of the td?
  alert("column " + columnPosition + "is clicked")
});
</script>
```

Comment: Trick the parental element into attaching a GPS tracking system.

Comment: @AdamDavis That solution only works until child element hits adolescence.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
<script>
$("td").click(function(){
  //how do i get the position of the td?
  alert("column " + $(this).parent().children().index(this) + " is clicked")
});
</script>
```

edit: I tested it, and it works

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, and this is good

```
<div>First div</div>
<div>Second div</div>
<div>Third div</div>
<div>Fourth div</div>

<script>
 $( "div" ).click(function() {
    // `this` is the DOM element that was clicked
    var index = $( "div" ).index( this );
    $( "span" ).text( "That was div index #" + index );
 });
</script>
```

---

[refer here](http://api.jquery.com/index/)